# How to count patterns in each row separately in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, count, pattern-matching

I am looking at all the possible combinations of 0's and 1's in a sequence of length 4. Thus, I have 2^4 lines in a dataframe or a list. (I don't mind the format as long as each combination can be looked at separately). In these combinations I am searching for particular *overlapping* patterns.

```
patterns=["00","101","1100"]
```

As a result, in the first combination of "0000" I'd like Python to tell me that it found 3 incidences (I don't care which ones out of the three). 
I found functions like search() but they only give the overall number of patterns for **all** the 16 combinations, not each one separately. Plus, I cannot fit into the right data style. Have tried str.count() but again does not seem to work for me even after converting the dataframe into a string.
The best that I could come up with was:

```
import itertools
sequ=[x for x in itertools.product(states,repeat=n)] #generates all the 
possible seq-s of the variable
from re import finditer
patterns=["00","101","1100"]
for match in finditer(patterns, sequ):
print(match.span())
```

However this only approximately works for simple patterns, e.g., `patterns=["00"]`

Comment: Show us a sample input and output.  It's very difficult to figure out what you want from what you've posted here.

Comment: This description is hard to understand. Show the data and the desried output and then describe how you want to go from data to output.

Comment: (And when you show the data, make a [MCVE], not a dataframe with thousands of rows.)

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no clarity in your question. Also, why is this tagged "dataframe"? Are you using pandas anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def main():
    n = int(input("Enter number of digits: "))
    for i in range(0, 1<<n):
        gray=i^(i>>1)
        print ("{:0{}b}".format(gray,n))

main()

#Input: 4
#Output:
#0000
#0001
#0011
#0010
#0110
#0111
#0101
#0100
#1100
#1101
#1111
#1110
#1010
#1011
#1001
#1000
```

I think this is what you're looking for.
There's no need to use a dataframe for this. It is bit flipping

EDIT:

```
def graylist(n):
    outlist = []
    for i in range(0, 1<<n):
        gray=i^(i>>1)
#        print ("{:0{}b}".format(gray,n))
        outlist.append('{:0{}b}'.format(gray,n))
    return outlist

alist = graylist(4)

def countingpattern(alist, string):

    count = 0
    for item in alist:
        for i in range(len(item)):
            if item[i:i+len(string)] == string:
                count += 1
    return count

print (countingpattern(alist, '00')) #12
print (countingpattern(alist, '101')) #4
print (countingpattern(alist, '1100')) #1
```

To see all patterns, we can then put the results in a dictionary.

```
def countingpatterndict(alist, string):
    adict = {}
    for item in alist:
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(item)):
            if item[i:i+len(string)] == string:
                count += 1
            adict[item] = count
    return adict

print (countingpatterndict(alist, '00')) 
#'0000': 3, '0001': 2, '0011': 1, '0010': 1, ...
print (countingpatterndict(alist, '101'))
#'1110': 0, '1010': 1, '1011': 1, ...
print (countingpatterndict(alist, '111'))
#'1101': 0, '1111': 2, '1110': 1, ...
```

Further edit:

```
def graylist(n):
    outlist = []
    for i in range(0, 1<<n):
        gray=i^(i>>1)
        outlist.append('{:0{}b}'.format(gray,n))
    return outlist

def countingpatterndict(alist, string):
    adict = {}
    for item in alist:
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(item)):
            if item[i:i+len(string)] == string:
                count += 1
            adict[item] = count
    return adict

alist = graylist(20)
import time
import pandas as pd
z1 = time.clock()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(countingpatterndict(alist, '101'), orient='index')
z2 = time.clock() - z1
print (z2) #5.716345938402242 seconds
print (df)
df.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Comment: thanks for this. I can actually get this far, what I can't is count the patterns. I get to your output within the first two lines of the code provided.

Comment: @Lola so what exactly do you want? Can you provide sample input and expected output in your question?

Comment: I would like to have a vector whose entries would give me the count of how many patterns were matched in every line (every line is a four digit combination like in your output). Thus, a vector of len 16. E.g., for the first two entries in this vector I'd like to see (3,2,...). I.e., there were three patterns mathed in the combination "0000" and two in "0001". Let me know if still does not make sense. =)

Comment: The input is exactly what you have as output in your code.

Comment: @Lola I've editted the answer. This should help you.

Comment: Thanks for this. It indeed put me forward, but the problem stays in that I get again (just like with the search function) the overall number of patterns in all the 16 lines. What I am looking for is a separate count because each line is a separate Markov chain...

Comment: @Lola Have you see the `countingpatterndict()` I've created? It gives a separate count for each pattern that exists in each string input. Not sure what else you require here. Please try out the code because it is exactly what you stated you want

Comment: I don't need each pattern separately. As I stated in my question, I don't mind exactly which pattern occurs but I do need each line regarded separately. (Each line is a four digit combination).

Comment: In order to use your output I, then, need to come up with the idea of how to sum *countingpatterndict()* in order to see how many patterns happened in the string "0000". I.e., an action would be 3+0+0 for this particular string.

Comment: Or maybe there is a way of how I can put all the three patterns at once into the *countingpatterndict()*. I.e., smth like 
    `countingpatterndict(alist, repr('00'or'101'or'111'))`

Comment: @Lola, why can't you simply use a `for` loop with a `list` of string patterns you want and pump it in? Then do a sum of the dictionary values for similar keys?

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought that I should avoid loops at every price and use numpy instead or similar. I've solved my task in R using loops but since my chains are actually of length 20 and not 4, R takes days to run it. That is why I am now trying to switch to Python...

Comment: @Lola It didn't take very long for me to do a `countingpatterndict()` for length 20, pattern 101. Its about 6 seconds. Please see further edit in answer.